# TinyMCE Comment

Tags: python, tinymce

I have a problem with the Tiny MCE Comment. When I use this command:

```
setup: function (editor) {
            editor.on('init', function () {
                editor.execCommand("ToggleSidebar", false, "showcomments");
            });
        }
```

But it not show the box to type text.
[image]

Comment: In my testing, that code appears to work. Here is a demo: https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/G8haab Can you modify that fiddle to reproduce your problem? If so, fork it, and please add it as an example to your question.

Comment: Hi @TinyLincoln, I updated my description. That image was not show the box to type text like your demo.

Comment: Hi @TinyLincoln, class "tox-sidebar" auto added style="width: 0px;" and class "tox-sidebar__slider tox-sidebar--sliding-growing tox-sidebar--sliding-open" auto added style="width: 0px;"